# Command to create alignment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, arrays

Consider the following mwe:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}    
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
        \begin{tabular}{r@{\hspace{5pt}}c@{\hspace{5pt}}c@{\hspace{5pt}}c@{\hspace{5pt}}l}
        6: &2&\hspace*{-1em}$\phantom{2}\cdot 3$&&\\
        15: &&\hspace{2.25pt}3&\hspace*{-1em}$\phantom{3}\cdot 5$&\\
        \hline
        $\mathrm{LCM}(6,15)=$ &2&\hspace*{-1em}$\phantom{2}\cdot 3$&\hspace*{-1em}$\phantom{3}\cdot 5$&$=30$
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
        \begin{tabular}{r@{\hspace{5pt}}c@{\hspace{5pt}}c@{\hspace{5pt}}c@{\hspace{5pt}}c@{\hspace{5pt}}l}
        24: &2&2&2&3&\\
        36: &2&2&&3&3\\
        \hline
        $\mathrm{LCM}(24,36)=$ &2&2&2&3&$3=72$
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:
[image]

I would like your input as to how to better achieve the same result and possibly with a command or the like. Note that the first example I forced the desired result but as you can see in the second, it becomes a bit cumbersome. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are looking for but this simplifies the markup in the first version with cdot.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}    
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\def\\{\aftergroup\zapdot\tabularnewline}}c@{{}\cdot{}}}
\let\xcdot\cdot
\def\zapdot{\def\cdot{\mathbin{\phantom\xcdot}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
        $\begin{array}{r@{\quad}CCc@{}l}
        6:&2&3\\
        15:&\aftergroup\zapdot&3& 5\\
        \hline
        \mathrm{LCM}(6,15)=&2&3&5&{}=72
        \end{array}$
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
        $\begin{array}{rccccl}
        24: &2&2&2&3&\\
        36: &2&2&&3&3\\
        \hline
        \mathrm{LCM}(24,36)={} &2&2&2&3&3=72
        \end{array}$
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I like the level of sorcery necessary to make such a code :P